# Change Button background color with ripple

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-theme, android-styles

Added this bit of code to my styles.xml file to change the primary color of the buttons to be a green which is the colorPrimary.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Then I tried combining it with the ripple effect since I read in another stack post that you need to create a ripple_effect xml file and use it as the background for the button. Then set the style of the button to the custom style detailed in style.xml.

How I linked to button in editor

[image]

What am I doing wrong. Is there an easier way to achieve adding both a ripple effect to the button and a colour. I have been trying to fix this with stack overflow posts but every solution seems different. I am on API 23.

Answer (score 1):

That can be achieved using `ThemeOverlay`s.

Having this in `res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="GreenButtonTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

And in your xml:

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Button"
  android:theme="@style/GreenButtonTheme" />
```

Then you'll get this output:

[image]

<sup>See [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/coloring-buttons-with-themeoverlays-background-tints.html) for more details.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use setColorFilter():

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```